# What is the Python/PyDev equivalent to org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am interested in modifying an existing plugin -- [rabbit-eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/rabbit-eclipse/) -- that tracks time spent editing different java elements (classes, methods, etc.). The plugin currently tracks Java elements via the [org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaElement.html) interface. I would like to add the ability to track the different Python elements.

I have installed PyDev in Eclipse and looked through the included JAR files, but I'm unable to figure out which class would be the equivalent to IJavaElement (if it even exists).

What is the PyDev equivalent to IJavaElement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev doesn't provide an actual replacement for IJavaElement... (i.e.: it does not provide selection based on that).

Still, there may be different approaches which may work... one choice would be hearing regular text selections and doing what's done in org.python.pydev.editor.actions.PyMethodNavigation, which is finding out the scope from the current location using FastParser.firstClassOrFunction(doc, startLine, searchForward, pyEdit.isCythonFile()) -- would that be enough for what you want?